# Java getResource() unexpected path

Tags: java

I wanted the url of a resource in the following form

> C:/Users/.../build/classes/jam/lena1.png

To achieve this I wrote the following code

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("lena1.png").getPath());
```

but it returns

> /C:/Users/.../build/classes/jam/lena1.png

Why is the extra forward slash appearing before the url?

Comment: if System.out.println(getClass().getResource("lena1.png").toString()); is written then output is : file:/C:/Users/.../build/classes/jam/lena1.png

Comment: I'm getting the resource, but the method getPath() returns the URL with an additional forward slash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regard that Class.getResource() returns a *URL*, and *URLs* are not only *file paths*: A URL involves a protocol, a host, a port, and a path. And it has its own notation and format.

What you are getting in your example is the *path* part of the URL, and the path always starts by a slash, according to [RFC2396](http://www.w3.org/2002/11/dbooth-names/rfc2396-numbered_clean.htm).

If you want to get a File from a URL, you could use `new File(url.toURI())`... assumming that the input URL is actually referencing a local file path.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but url.toURI() doesn't work, it gives the same result.

Comment: I insist: First, get a URI from the URL with _url.toURI()_, then create a File object passing the URI as a parameter. Then, if you want the absolute local path, you can get it with _file.getAbsolutePath()_.

Comment: but there is a little problem, tthis method returns path with back slash

Comment: If you're running your program on a Windows plattform, the correct path separator is the back slash. Is it a problem for you? Realise that the value returned by _file.getAbsolutePath()_ *is* a valid path.

Comment: Yes, its a valid path but in java if the path has backslash it should be something like "C:\\Users\\..." but instead it is like "C:\Users\..."

Comment: Ah, ah. That is another issue: If you want to embed the path into a Java source code file, you have to escape it propperly: If it must be within a string, you'll have to replace each occurence of back slash by a double back slash, and each occurence of double quote by a back slash + double quote. For this matter, use _path.replaceAll("\\","\\\\")_ and then _path.replaceAll("\"","\\\"")_

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a URL, not a filename.

The question itself is odd. What do you care what the path of the URL is?

Comment: I need the path for using it in an external library.

Answer (score -1):

Leading slash to denote the root of the classpath. Try this : `System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/lena1.png").getPath());`

Comment: The root of the CLASSPATH isn't C:/, and your suggested code isn't correct either: it should be `"/jam/lena1.png"`.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
String s = (getClass().getResource("lena1.png").getPath()).substring(1);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: This will remove the slash, but doesn't not clarify why it is there.